# Spring Boot Gradle setup

Tags: eclipse, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I tried to setup `gradle` in `eclipse Luna` for a simple `spring boot` application, but none of the jars are downloaded. Can anyone give me an idea of what I'm missing ?
I ran `gradle clean build` in the command line and it compiles successfully:
[image: gradle clean build in workspace folder]
This is the content of my  `build.gradle` file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'sample'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
}
```

This is the content of the class with the controller:

```
package sample;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/sample")
    public String sampleIt(){
        return "Hello! Welcome to Spring Boot Sample. ";
    }
}
```

This is the class with the main function :

```
package sample;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println(ctx.getDisplayName());

        System.out.println("This is my first Spring Boot Example");

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have the gradle plugin for eclipse?

Comment: @mh-dev Yes, I do. I installed it by following the steps from this site : https://pbaris.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/install-gradle-plugin-for-eclipse/ .

Comment: How did you add the project to eclipse?

Comment: I just created a new Gradle project, created two classes and copy-pasted the code.

Comment: You need to import the gradle project into eclipse .Not just open the code

Comment: Thank you @mh-dev, importing the project worked. Is there a way of creating such a project from scratch, without the need to import an existing one ?

Comment: There's gradle plugin that allows to create an eclipse project. The spring project creator from http://start.spring.io/ creates a gradle file that contains that plugin. But you should not do that. Just import it as a gradle plugin. Eclipse has this weird "import" workflow, which is in my opinion often just a open.

Comment: Thank you very much, @mh-dev.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer from the comment:*

It is necessary to install the gradle plugin and import the gradle project afterwards. (Don't forget to click the 'Build Model' button)